# How to remote debug opendaylight oxigen release in eclipse

Tags: opendaylight

I wanted to remote debug opendaylight controller project in eclipse.
I built the controller project and started the karaf using "./karaf debug".
I also got message "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005" in console. but when I try to remote debug this port from eclipse, I got "Failed to connect to remote VM" in error message.

please help me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://lists.opendaylight.org/pipermail/dev/2018-August/005233.html, again: Have you checked if that JVM is really running on port 5005 on localhost,
doing e.g. a "telnet localhost 5005" ? You may have a local firewall?

You'll also want to make sure that your Eclipse and your ODL started with
the exact same JVM. Especially on Windows, that is sometimes not the case.

Most importantly (and further to the original email reply), the default port in the Eclipse UI for remote debugging is 8000.  You wouldn't just have forgotten to change that to 5005, would you? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. when I execute "telnet localhost 5005" getting below messages :
Trying 127.0.0.1...
in karaf console also I am getting "Debugger failed to attach: timeout during handshake" message when I try to telnet. 

also executed "netstat -nlp | grep 5005" command and got below output :
"tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5005            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8252/java".

Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: This really isn't an ODL issue - I would suggest posting to the eclipse community.

Comment: @RajeshKumar based on your telnet, it seems like your Karaf JVM is listening on port 5005 for debug. If you connect from Eclipse, I think the most likely explanation is that your forgot to change the debug port in Eclipse from 8000 to 5005 or that you are running your Eclipse and ODL Karaf on different JVM versions that are incompatible.